# Drop Down Menu - populated from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 table in a database and I would like to populate two dropdown menu with  value from 'brands and categories' table, so that a user can select categories and brands and then a search or a display page would be produced on the basis of their selections from products table

I am fairly new to php, but have a MySQL database to which I can add/edit/del and produce results from, but am unsure how to do the above..

I have 3 tables

1. brands:

   ```
    brand_id
    brand_title
   ```
2. categories:

   ```
   cat_id
   cat_title
   ```
3. products:

   ```
   product_id
   product_cat
   product_brand
   product_price
   product_keywords
   ```

my php code here: 
This code fetch data from brands and categories table in 2 dropdown.
now i want to search by keywords and display data from product table by what options selected from brands and categories table.
please take a look this link:
http://ruqayyahfashion.com/product/1.php

```
<?Php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("ecomerce")or die("Connection Failed");


$sql="SELECT cat_id, cat_title FROM categories"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

$options=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{ 
$cat_id=$row["cat_id"]; 
$cat_title=$row["cat_title"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$cat_id\">".$cat_title; 
} 


$sql1="SELECT brand_id, brand_title FROM brands"; 
$result1=mysql_query($sql1); 

$options1=""; 

while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))

{ 
$brand_id=$row1["brand_id"]; 
$brand_title=$row1["brand_title"]; 
$options1.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$brand_id\">".$brand_title; 
} 


?> 

<form >
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search a Product">
<SELECT NAME=Categories> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Select a Category 
<?=$options?> 
</SELECT> 

<SELECT NAME=Brands> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Select a Brand 
<?=$options1?> 
</SELECT> 

<button type="submit" name="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct, only you've forgot to close the OPTION-tags

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$cat_id\">".$cat_title."</OPTION>"; 
$options1.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$brand_id\">".$brand_title."</OPTION>";
```

Also make it in HTML code for empty Select options

```
<OPTION VALUE="0">Select a Brand</OPTION>
```

To get a results you'll need to create another php - for an example dowork.php where you'll make your query on base of the costumer selection.
You'll receive costumer choice in $_POST['Brand'] and $_POST['Categories'].
But to got this you need first modify your HTML:

1. tag FORM:
2. Look on whole your html code and correct names and values - almost everywhere you're missed "

Comment: this code is correct but  i want to search selected items from products table.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the second drop down to be populated based on what option was selected in the first drop down?

Comment: OK, I'll modify my answer, wait a minute

Comment: i meant i want to fetch data from product table by what options selected from brands and categories table. Thanks

Comment: OK, I saw it but if you like to make it by pure php you need 2 passes - first you choice brand and category, after that you'll go to php script and will generate appropriate list of products and will generate new page - now with products. For now you've creted code for first pass. I've told you what you have to do to go to second pass.

Comment: Of course there is another solution but then you need to use AJAX.